# Custom Domain URl for a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dns

I have this URL of my web application:
http://application.com/academies/1

now I want that my customer can map this url and get

http://my-academy.com/

Examples:

- http://application.com/academies/1/dashboard

**-->** http://my-academy.com/dashboard

- http://application.com/academies/1/dashboard/courses

**-->** http://my-academy.com/dashboard/courses

(this below is too hard to do?)

- http://application.com/users/edit

**-->** http://my-academy.com/users/edit

Comment: When you say "my customer" do you mean "a user who is associated with the Academy with id=1"?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a URL rewrite. If you are using apache as webserver you can add below rewrite rules.

```
RewriteRule ^/academies/1/(.*)  http://my-academy.com/$1
RewriteRule http://application.com/users/edit   http://my-academy.com/users/edit
```

For ruby-on-rails [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) article should help you.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to automatize this procedure